# NetApp ONTAP certificate expiry_time format

Tags: certificate, netapp, self-signed-certificate, ontap

I want to configure an expiration period of 5 years for a root CA certificate on NetApp ONTAP via its API.

The [`expiry_time`](https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMLP2879970/html/resources/security_certificate.html#netapp_ontap.resources.security_certificate.SecurityCertificateSchema.expiry_time) is documented like this:

> `expiry_time`
>
> Certificate expiration time. Can be provided on POST if creating self-signed certificate. The expiration time range is between 1 day to 10 years.

An example for 365 days is `P365DT`. I am not aware of a format to specify time periods like this. Can someone tell me how this works? How do I specify 5 years in that format?

Comment: Do you not have support for this via NetApp themselves? If so drop them a line first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a *cheap* workaround, you can of course calculate the number of days for 5 years and just use

```
P1825DT
```

as the expiry time period. But there is a name for that format and it also supports years. The format is defined in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) and is used to describe *durations*.

The string always starts with **P** for period. It can then be followed by **Y**ears, **M**onths, **W**eeks and/or **D**ays. If you also want to specify **H**ours, **M**inutes and/or **S**econds, append a **T** for time first and then add the desired values. Example for 5 years:

```
P5Y
```

Example for 8 years, 5 months, 20 days, 13 hours and 37 minutes:

```
P8Y5M20DT13H37M
```